# Initialize and declare variable in if-else condition in JAVA

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to initialize and declare variable in if-else condition in JAVA, but it is not executing, can someone please help me in below code?

This is the method, which I'm calling from main method. But it's not executing the initialization under if condition and failing.

```
    public static void getData(String funct) {
            try {
                    if ("lob".equals(funct)) {
                            String sql1= String.format("select distinct lob_name from BPUSH_lobs order by lob_name");
                    }
                    else {
                            String sql1= String.format("select distinct env_type from BPUSH_environments order by env_type");
                    }
                    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.23.240.41:1521:BCTOOLS","AMCOPR","AMCOPR");

                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rst;

                    System.out.println(funct);

                    rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);

                    while (rst.next()) {
                            String lobName = rst.getString("lob_name");
                            System.out.format("%s\n",lobName);
                    }

                    conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

}

PLEASE HELP :) 
Thanks,

Comment: what seems to be the `failing` about?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Stackoverflow, will try to follow the process. 
Allow me to edit my question. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Declare sql1 outside if-else as below,

```
    String sql1= "";

    if ("lob".equals(funct)) {
       sql1= String.format("select distinct lob_name from BPUSH_lobs order by lob_name");
    } else {
       sql1= String.format("select distinct env_type from BPUSH_environments order by env_type");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, 

I'm getting this error now - sql1 is already defined in getData method,

showJobs.java:38: sql1 is already defined in getData(java.lang.String)
                                String sql1= String.format("select distinct lob_name from BPUSH_lobs order by lob_name");
                                       ^

Comment: Hi Abhijeet, that is because you are creating sql1 again in if-else condition. Please see if-else block in answer above carefully.

Comment: Yes Santosh, understood. :) Thanks, it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable inside of block, you cannot access that from outside.

Declare `String sql1` outside if statement and change the value.

Comment: I tried defining variable outside try block, getting new error 

It says sql1 is already defined in getData method. 

showJobs.java:38: sql1 is already defined in getData(java.lang.String) String sql1= String.format("select distinct lob_name from BPUSH_lobs order by lob_name"); ^

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable "**String sql1**" out side the try block and initialize it with null "**String sql1=null;**" This must solve your problem.

Comment: I tried defining variable outside try block, getting new error 

showJobs.java:38: sql1 is already defined in getData(java.lang.String)
                                String sql1= String.format("select distinct lob_name from BPUSH_lobs order by lob_name");
                                       ^

Comment: String sql1 is already defined outside try block. Why you define it again?  Remove the definition and use it as "sql1= String.format .."

Answer (score 0):

Santosh's Answer is correct. Adding an explanation, as to WHY?

It is in fact initializing the variable **sql1** (that too 2 variables), but you are unable to see that for the simple reason that, the variable is available only in the scope where it is declared.

You have declared two different variables both named **sql1** but in different scopes, one inside the **if block** and another inside the **else block**

And when you try to access the variable outside the scope, it is throwing an exception.

Solution: Declare the variable, outside the if/else block, i.e. in the beginning of the **getData** method, and only assign the values inside the if/else blocks. This will solve your problem.

```
String sql1 = "";

try{ 
   if(condition){
      sql1= "<something>";
   }
   else{
     sql1= "<something else>";
   }
}
```